# python pdfminer - KeyError 'AcroForm'

Tags: python, keyerror, pdfminer

I have a script that is getting the attachment filename and if the ext indicates a pdf file, it runs it through the following code.  However I'm receiving the KeyError below.  I cannot find any information on how to correct or troubleshoot.  I have successfully run PDF forms through this script previously, not sure why this is not functioning as expect.

```
 if ext == '.PDF' or ext == '.pdf':
      item_field_list = []
      item_number = str(random.randint(1000000, 9999999))
      #try:
      with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
           verify_item = 0
           tmp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
           parser = PDFParser(tmp)
           doc = PDFDocument(parser)
           fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distributionitemimport.py", line 87, in <module>
    fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']
KeyError: 'AcroForm'
```

When I do a `print(doc.catalog)` I get the following:

```
{'MarkInfo': {'Marked': True}, 'Lang': b'en-US', 'Type': /'Catalog', 'StructTree
Root': <PDFObjRef:162>, 'Pages': <PDFObjRef:2>}
```

Comment: What would you see printed if you do `print(doc.catalog)` before the problematic line?

Comment: @alecxe I've updated to include. Thanks!

Comment: What does `resolve1` return when you call `resolve1(doc.catalog)`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Looks like: `<class 'dict'>`

Comment: My guess is it's either secured with a password, encrypted or both. Unfortunately, I don't presently know what to do about it and am struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that in your collection of pdfs there are some pdfs with no AcroForm. First, remove all pdf without AcroForm

I suggest making a new folder and put one pdf that contains AcroForm and checks your code. It will work